# posts_orderby filter with multiple meta values - Wordpress 3.9.1

Tags: php, wordpress

There is the problem...

I have a custom post type with multiple meta_values (like years, collection number, pages, ...)

I want to order the post in this order : year, collection number, pages

There is my code

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'   => '_year'
);

add_filter('posts_orderby','orderbyreplace');
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
remove_filter('posts_orderby','orderbyreplace');
```

In my functions.php

```
function orderbyreplace($orderby) {  
    $orderby = '_year.meta_value+0 DESC, _collection_number.meta_value+0 DESC, _pages.meta_value+0 DESC';

    return $orderby;
}
```

But when I applied the filter, I have 0 result.

My wordpress version is 3.9.1

My meta values is _year, _collection_number and _pages

Any idea ?

Comment: I'm always looking for a solution :'(